# Logger Not Storing Recorded Information to File After a Crash

Tags: c++, logging

Well, what good is a logger if it only keeps a record when things go well?

It is a very simple thing, the logger, that I wanted to test before I expanded it:

// Logger.h

```
class Logger : boost::noncopyable
{    
public:
    static void write(std::string const& msg, int line, std::string const& file);

private:
    Logger();

private:
    static std::ofstream m_sOut;
};

#define LOG(msg) Logger::write(msg, __LINE__, __FILE__)
```

// Logger.cpp

```
std::ofstream Logger::m_sOut("Logfile");

void Logger::write(const std::string &msg, int line, const std::string &file, Level level /* = Info */)
{
    m_sOut << file << ":  " << line << ":  " << msg << "\n";
}
```

I fear that this is too simple. If I exit the program normally, it outputs as expected to my logfile. However, if there is a crash, there is no output.

What do I have to do to ensure that it outputs to a log regardless of a crash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on when it crashes, I would say. If it's *during* the log output, all bets are off.

First I would make sure that the log output gets flushed after every invocation, so I'd use `std::endl` instead of `\n` in `write()`. You'd also have to verify that this would indeed be sufficient or if you have to take additional steps to ensure that the stream you're using doesn't buffer writes.

Edit: As pointed out in the comments, writing through to the disk without caching/buffering of any sort is slow and expensive. It's a trade off - if you absolutely must have the requirement that you can't lose any log info unless the program crashes *during* the log statement, you probably have to do it that way. I probably would relax that requirement a little and just rely on the behaviour of `std::endl` that should result in the stream being flushed; This still leaves the buffers below the stream like the OS buffers in place but you've got a pretty good chance that you won't lose any log output.

Comment: Flushing after every invocation (as with flag FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH) is **very** expensive and slow, avoid it when possible.

Comment: @ruslik, you're right, it's not the cheap option, but it depends on how stringent the requirements are when it comes to the reliability of the logging.

Comment: I wanted to say that by using fflush in the lazy way (from unhandled exception filter) the problem is solved with minimum effort and without sacrificing the speed. If it should be made really safe (with separate process, as sugested by @Preet) then the whole architecture should be changed.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is requires your logging subsystem to be at least in a separately managed process and you should communicate with via a high bandwidth protocol - such as shared memory.

Answer (score 1):

On windows, you can use [SetUnhandledExceptionFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680634%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to flush the log file.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to flush after writing:

```
m_sOut.flush();
```